# Singularities of the Coordinate Systems

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, singularities, kerr-metric

We know that, the singularity of the Schwarzschild metric at $r=2M$ can be removable via coordinate transformation to  Kruskal-Szekers . Can we apply a similar argument to the Kerr metric? If so, what's the name of this coordinate system?

Comment: There are uncountably infinitely many different such coordinate systems. I described one example in the second half of [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/590229).